# Recursive Fibonacci in C - plain simple

Tags: c

I'm trying write a **recursive** fibonacci() in c

I have

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fibonacci(int);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

   int option;
   printf("1- Calculate Fibonacci\n");
   printf("2- Exit\n");
   scanf("%d", &option);

   if(option == 1){

     int limit;
     printf("Enter and integer: ");
     scanf("%d", &limit);

     printf("The Fibonacci sequence is : \n");

     fibonacci(limit);

    }else if(option == 2){
        return 0;
    }else{
        printf("Please select your option :  1 or 2.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}


int fibonacci(int n){

   if ( n == 0 )
      return 0;
   else if ( n == 1 )
      return 1;
   else
      return ( fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2) );
}
```

---

After compile, and run I got

```
./a.out 
1- Calculate Fibonacci
2- Exit
1
Enter and integer: 5
The Fibonacci sequence is :
```

---

I never get my number printing out.

Any hints on what I forgot ?

Comment: I saw a lot of title using fork, so I created one without using fork.

Comment: So if you see a lot of people jumping out of the window from the 3rd floor, you jump too ? ;-)

Comment: Note: With `return ( fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2) );`, and input `n`, code will make about `O(fibonacci(n))` recursive calls.  By making a helper function that retrieves `Fib(n)` and `Fib(n-1)`, code only needs to make about `n` recursive calls.  With `n=40`, this is about 330,000,000 calls versus 40.  Once your `print` issue is fixed, try n=46 - takes a long time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace:

```
printf("The Fibonacci sequence is : \n");

fibonacci(limit);
```

with

```
printf("The Fibonacci sequence is : %d \n",fibonacci(limit));
```

or

```
int result;
result = fibonacci(limit);
printf("The Fibonacci sequence is : %d \n",result);
```

Answer (score 3):

`fibonacci(limit);` does not print anything even though your code theoretically "works".

Comment: Thanks. `printf("%d", fibonacci(limit));` solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

You don't print anything in fibonacci(int) method.

Answer (score 0):

```
fibonacci(limit);
```

This line is not printing anything, you return your answer in some result in some variable or print it simply by `printf("%d", fibonacci(limit));`